# HTML + ul li alignment center

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a `ul li` list, I am trying to align `li` to center of the `ul`.
I have attached my HTML code and CSS.

Important: On `li hover` I have added some animation (`margin-top`).

Expected output: Align `li` to the center of `ul` without affecting `li`,

```css
#content-right {
  border-top: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: left;
}

#content-right {
  float: left;
  height: 159px;
}

#partner-icons {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#partner-icons li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 14%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
}

#partner-icons li figure {
  color: #e90e0e;
}

#partner-icons li img {
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#partner-icons li figure {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#partner-icons li:hover figure {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-right">
  <ul id="partner-icons" class="cf">
    <li id="first">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/cat-icon.png">
      </figure>
      ABCDEF
    </li>
    <li id="second">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/cat-icon.png">
      </figure>
      GHJIDDK
    </li>
    <li id="fifth">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/cat-icon.png">
      </figure>
      FDSNOISD
    </li>
    <li id="sixth">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/cat-icon.png">
      </figure>
      GDSFDSDSD
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried my self to align it to center, I changed the CSS of li (float:none), It's working fine but on hover animation is not working.
Please, can anyone help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left` and add `vertical-align: top;` to `li`, by default `inline-block` elements are aligned to baseline that's why removing margin affects all `li` elements.

```css
#content-right {
  border-top: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  float: left;
}

#content-right {
  float: left;
  height: 159px;
}

#partner-icons {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#partner-icons li {
  list-style: none;
  /*float: left;*/
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 14%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#partner-icons li figure {
  color: #e90e0e;
}

#partner-icons li img {
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#partner-icons li figure {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

#partner-icons li:hover figure {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-right">
  <ul id="partner-icons" class="cf">
    <li id="first">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/cat-icon.png">
      </figure>
      Offers
    </li>
    <li id="second">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/cat-icon.png">
      </figure>
      Fantasy Football
    </li>
    <li id="fifth">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/cat-icon.png">
      </figure>
      Find a Job
    </li>
    <li id="sixth">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/256/cat-icon.png">
      </figure>
      Buy Sell
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, You save my time lot.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)